# How to filter 2 CSV files in Mule?

Tags: mule, mule-studio, anypoint-studio, dataweave, mulesoft

I have used the 'ParseTemplate' component in the Anypoint studio to get data from a .csv file. I have used two .csv files in this scenario. Like this: [image: my flows]

I want to filter these 2 payloads where the content which is not in 1st file and but which is in the second file should be displayed as a final JSON response.

Like 1st CSV file has 10 fields having id from 1-10, the second file consists of the fields present in 1st CSV file + 5 more fields having id's 11-15.

I want to display these 5 unique fields only, which is not present in the 1st file.
How to achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

It is a lot easier if you provide input data and the expected output.
Moreover, I am not sure whether you want DW 1.0 or 2.0 code.  So here's the DW 2.0 code:

```
%dw 2.0
output application/csv
// Get the headers to remove--I assume the 1st file is in the payload
var hs2rm = payload[0] pluck $$
// Read the second CSV--not sure how you do it since I do not see the details
// of parseTemplate.
var csv = readUrl("classpath://other.csv","application/csv")
---
// Iterate over the records of the second CSV file
csv map (
    // Remove the headers of the 2nd CSV that match the headers of the 1st
    $ -- hs2rm
)
```

Here's the DW 1.0 expression to do the same as above:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/csv

// Get the headers to remove--I assume the 1st file is in the payload
%var fs2rm = payload[0] pluck $$
// Read the second CSV
%var csv = readUrl("classpath://other.csv","application/csv")
// Define a function to iterate over the object and remove fields
// passed in a list of :key types (i.e. not :string)
%function rmFields(o,fs) 
    o mapObject (
        {}  when (fs contains $$)
            otherwise {($$):$}
    )
---
// Iterate over the records of the second CSV file
csv map (
    // Remove the headers of the 2nd CSV that match the headers of the 1st
    // There is no convenient way to do it in DW 1.0 as in DW 2.0
    rmFields($, fs2rm)
)
```

Now that you have provided the sample for the inputs and the expected output I know what you are looking for--because the original description at the top is at the very least not clear--and I can provide you with the code.  Here it is:

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/json
%var firstcsv = flowVars.set_1stpayload
%var secondcsv = flowVars.set_2ndpayload
---
secondcsv -- firstcsv
```

Comment: I have used 'Parse Template' to read both files that are CSV1 and CSV2 like showed in the attached image. Could you please give me a dataweave expression for this scenario? I am unable to get that above dataweave you have mentioned. Also, I want dataweave 1.0 for this. Thanks.

Comment: Are you successful I reading the CSV files?  Also note that hardcoding paths like you do is not recommended.  I will provide you with the DW 1.0 code in a few minutes.

Comment: Thank you so much. I appreciate it. @george

Comment: I tried to implement your logic, but unfortunately, I am not quite getting it. Could you please tell me how can I achieve this using dataweave variables? I have stored both the payloads in vars in LinkedHashMap. Like this: `%dw 1.0
%output application/java
%var firstcsv = flowVars.set_1stpayload
%var secondcsv = flowVars.set_2ndpayload` How can filter id's using this?

Comment: Replace where you see `payload` with `firstcsv` and `csv` with `secondcsv`.  Also remove this line `%var csv = readUrl("classpath://other.csv","application/csv")`

Comment: I tried this one, but it's showing all the genders of employees. I want to display all the fields having id 10-15.

Comment: Pass me sample data please otherwise we may as well call it a day.

Comment: `id,name,age,gender,address
1,luis,21,m,Pune
2,john,23,m,Hyderabad
3,laura,21,f,Delhi
4,beth,25,f,Aurangabad
5,matt,32,m,Kolkata
6,neha,34,f,Mumbai
7,shruti,23,f,Dehradun
8,charles,34,m,Kanpur
9,alex,24,m,Bihar
10,rohan,36,m,Chennai
` this is my 1st csv and I have converted it into arraylist using transform messge, and also 2nd csv have these 10 fields + 5 more fields having different id. I have stored these 2 payloads in the variables as I have mentioned.

Comment: Good now add the 2nd files sample data.  Finally give me what you want to see as an output.  Then I 'll give you the code

Comment: `id,name,age,gender,address
1,luis,21,m,Pune
2,john,23,m,Hyderabad
3,laura,21,f,Delhi
4,beth,25,f,Aurangabad
5,matt,32,m,Kolkata
6,neha,34,f,Mumbai
7,shruti,23,f,Dehradun
8,charles,34,m,Kanpur
9,alex,24,m,Bihar
10,rohan,36,m,Chennai
11,srishti,24,Delhi
12,nidhi,22,Kanpur
13,sakshi,33,Bhilai
14,rohini,22,Maharashtra
15,shree,22,Maharashtra` This one is the 2nd csv, converted and stored in arraylist in second var of dw. Now I want these 5 extra fileds which are not in 1st file to be displayed in JSON format. Please help me doing this with appropriate code. Thanks.

Comment: `11,srishti,24,Delhi
12,nidhi,22,Kanpur
13,sakshi,33,Bhilai
14,rohini,22,Maharashtra
15,shree,22,Maharashtra` only these should be displayed in JSON format.

Comment: Add the the solution in what you are looking for in my original answer.

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, man. But still, it is showing the whole list of 15 employees rather than 5 employees.

Comment: In that case you are not having an `ArrayList`s of `HashMap`s inside the `flowVars`.  Maybe you want to upload a sample project and I can have a look how you get the data

Comment: How can I upload the project? Should I paste the configuration XML of my mule flow?

Comment: github, google drive, etc. then add the link in here

Comment: In fact, here's a project I created that reads two files and gets the difference: https://github.com/gkarabotsos/csvdiff/blob/master/csv.zip . Do the same in your end and you should be fine.